# How to Show Added Elements Without Refreshing The Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form and a div for showing the message which is sent by form. I have to refresh the page after sending a message by form to see the messages in my div. However, I want to see the messages in div without refreshing the page, like a chatroom. I tried to use Ajax but I couldn't make it.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @message, remote:true do |f| %>

<%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>

<% end %>
```

And here is my controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @messagesAll = Message.all
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.all
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:user, :body))
    if @message.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.html {redirect_to messages_url}
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

end
```

And here is my div:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="messages-div">
    <ul class="media-list">
        <% @messagesAll.each do |post| %>
            <li class="media">
                <%= post.body %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: try using websocket

Comment: Is it easy to use? Because I couldn't use even Ajax. I'm new in programming.

Comment: If you are thinking of building a chatting application or if there are too many ajax calls to be made then websocket would be good choice, Rails 5 has websockets built into it, you can follow [this link](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable) to implement sockets. If you want to implement rails ajax you can follow [this post](https://sahilprjpt.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/voting-application-for-learning-rails-ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a div with an id of messages that you're rendering the messages in e.g.

```
<div id="messages">
  <%= render @messages %>
</div>
```

On your create action rails will look for a `create.js.erb` file.  So what you want is this in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
  format.html {redirect_to messages_url}
end
```

Then have a `create.js.erb` file:

```
$('#messages').append('<%= j render @message %>');
```

Edit: In your specific case you would need to target the ul. So your `create.js.erb` would be

```
$('#messages-div ul.media-list').append('<li class="media"><%= j @message.body %></li>');
```

j is just a shortcut for `escape_javascript`.  [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html)

That should get you started, but you'll want to do something else via ajax if the message isn't saved.

Comment: Message saved but still I have to refresh the page to see message in div.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the mark up for the rendering of your messages including the html.